# Implementing a D3.js chart in Wagtail

Tags: javascript, d3.js, wagtail

Is it possible to add custom D3 charts to the draftail editor and insert an interactive D3 chart in the body wherever we want (just the way we insert an image)? I was trying to find tutorials on this but I might be wording my questions wrong, if you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StreamField is a far better approach for mixed-media content than putting everything into a rich text field: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/topics/streamfield.html

Comment: Thanks, I will go through that and look up the advantages of it!

Comment: I managed to go through the documentation on streamfield, any suggestions how would I add a d3.js script as I could not really find anything on that topic.

Comment: I passed by RawHTMLBlock a few times, guess that is the solution but has its limitations. :)

Comment: That's a bit broad to answer here. You need to decide what data you're collecting on the edit form to represent a chart, and define a new block type with the relevant fields. For example, if chart data consists of a list of numbers along with a dropdown to select the chart type, you want a `StructBlock` consisting of a `ListBlock` of `DecimalBlocks` along with a `ChoiceBlock`. Alternatively, if it's appropriate for users to paste in chart data as a blob of JSON, it can be a single TextBlock. After that, write whatever template code you need to render that data through d3.js.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!